# Unable to implement nltk.stopwords

Tags: python, nltk

I am trying to remove stopwords in my data with nltk, but after several attempts I am unable to remove the stopwords. The tokenization part of my code works, but I am unable to understand why stopwords does not work.

```
def pre_process(text):
    
    # remove special characters and digits
    text=re.sub("(\\d|\\W|_)+"," ",text)
    text=re.split("\W+",text)
    
    return text
text = dat['text'].apply(lambda x:pre_process(x))
nltk.download('stopwords')

def remove_stopwords(text):
    for word in text:
        if word in stopwords.words('english'):
            text.remove(word)
        return text

text_stopword = text.apply(lambda x:remove_stopwords(x))
```

The code should remove words such as 'the', but after running my csv through the code, that words such as 'the' is still present.

Current results:

`text` returns:

`[tv, future, in, the, hands, of, viewers, with...`

`text_stopword` returns:

`[tv, future, in, the, hands, of, viewers, with...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your return statement in `remove_stopwords` function is wrongly indented. Due to that function returns text right after the first iteration.

Please go with:

```
def remove_stopwords(text):
    for word in text:
        if word in stopwords.words('english'):
            text.remove(word)
    return text
```